# Why a protected member of a class in a package in java is accessible in an other package class?

Tags: java, package

```
//first package is
package package1;
public class ClassA
{
    public void displayA()
    {
    System.out.println("Class A");
    }
}
//second package is
package package3;
public class ClassC
{
protected int m=10;
public void displayC()
    {
    System.out.println("Class C");
    System.out.println("m="+m);
    }
}
//importing the packages
import package1.ClassA;
import package3.*;
class PackageTest3
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ClassA objA=new ClassA();
        ClassC objC=new ClassC();
    objA.displayA();
    objC.displayC();
}
}
Output:
Class A
Class C
m=10
```

My question is in the above program even if the member (int m) in classA in package1 is            protected ,it is still accessed in the class PackageTest3. I am not getting this.Can anyone     help me?

Comment: I don't see you accessing `m` directly from `PackageTest3`. You are just calling a public method of that class, which of course can access it's own class member.

Comment: It isn't. Not a real question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The field is declared protected which would limit access to the field to classes derived from `ClassC` or are in the same package. **But** the main method is accessing a public method which prints the protected field's value to the console, it is **not** accessing the protected field directly.

Access to the field as demonstrated in the following example would be prevented by the `protected` access modifier:

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    ClassA objA = new ClassA();
    ClassC objC = new ClassC();
    objA.displayA(); //fine
    objC.displayC(); //fine
    System.out.println(objC.m); //Not Allowed, prevented by protected access
}
```

Comment: `protected` allows access by derived classes OR classes in the same package. The way I read your first sentence you are implying AND.

Comment: @kevin Bowersox Thanks a lot. Doubts vanished.